# inequality with binomial coefficients

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

I'd like to show that if $s \le n/4$, then we have
$$ {n \choose s-1} + {n \choose s-2}+ \dots {n \choose 0} \le {n \choose s}.$$
I'm happy with any short proof of this, but a "combinatorial proof" would be especially nice.

Comment: this is a special case of something listed as an "easy exercise" in Chapter 5 of Babai and Frankl's book. (See Proposition 5.13): [http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/CLASS/HANDOUTS-COMB/BaFrNew.pdf](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elaci/CLASS/HANDOUTS-COMB/BaFrNew.pdf)

Comment: What leads you to believe it's true?  Is it a homework assignment, something you've observed empirically, something else?

Comment: In a book, but without a solution and listed as an "easy exercise". Not a homework problem––I'm a professor, just trying to prepare my lecture. I added a link to a .pdf of the textbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short direct proof of your inequality for $ s \leq n/3$.

**Lemma:** For $ s \leq n/3$, $ {n \choose s } = \frac{n-s+1}{s} { n \choose s-1}  > 2 { n \choose s-1} $.

Then, it follows that

$$\begin{array} {r l l } { n \choose s } & > 2 { n \choose s-1} &  = { n \choose s-1} + { n \choose s-1} \\
& > { n \choose s-1 } + 2 {n \choose s-2}  & = { n \choose s-1} + { n \choose s-2} + { n \choose s-2}\\
& > {n\choose s-1 } + {n \choose s-2} + 2 { n \choose s-3} \\ 
& > \ldots \\
& > \sum { n \choose s-i}. \end{array} $$

---

One way to motivate the idea is via the induction part of proposition 5.13.

Answer (score 1):

Prove Proposition 5.13 in the book by induction.

> For $ n\geq 2s$, we have
> $$ { n \choose s } + {n \choose s-1 } + \ldots + { n \choose 0 } < { n \choose s } \times ( 1 + \frac{s}{n-2s+1} ). $$

It is indeed an easy exercise (when you know this is what you have to prove).

Then, follow the book for the next 2 lines:

> If $ s \leq n/ l $ then the right hand side is less than $ { n \choose s} \cdot  ( 1 + \frac{1}{ l - 2 } )$. For example, with $s \leq n/4$, we obtain the inequality
> $$ { n \choose s } + {n \choose s-1 } + \ldots + { n \choose 0 } < 2 \cdot { n \choose s } . $$

---

I'm not quite sure why he didn't pick $l = 3$ though. That is almost certainly a typo.